# truffle pet shop example question(address convert)

Tags: truffle, addresses

I have some question about truffle pet shop example ,here is the original link [pet shop](https://truffleframework.org/tutorials/pet-shop), when I work this command:truffle test , and I have some compile problem.

[image]

here is original code:

[image]

I have some compile issue that really don't understand , so I try to ask for help.

Thanks everyone read my question(help message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `this` referes the object of contract so you have to convert in address:

> You have to use cast :

`address expected = address(this);`

Comment: it work , really appreciate your help ..!!
the compile result is "3 passing" ..!

Answer (score 0):

The final result is working ...!!

[image]